# А в ASP.NET Core есть обычные Razor хелперы?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Осваиваю ASP.NET Core и не могу понять старые ASP.NET 4.6 Razor хелперы ещё есть?
Intellisence когда ввожу @helper его вообще не подсвечивает.

В 4.6 версии я создавал папку App_Code и в неё делал cshtml файл с хелперами
@helper ... после в любой вьюшке мог эти хелперы использовать. А как теперь с этим в ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Директива `@helper` была [убрана](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/pull/323) из Razor. Вместо нее придется использовать либо partial views, либо создавать [`ViewComponent`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html).

<sub>Многие разработчики этим фактом недовольны, так что, может быть, в будущем хэлперы вернут.</sub>